# Application-defined or object-defined error in setting column width

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run this code snippet to set the column width from the firstcolumn to the last one to 4.

I am getting the error saying: Application-defined or object-defined error

```
Dim firstRow, firstCol As Integer
Dim lastRow, lastCol As Integer
Dim row, column As Integer

firstRow = start.row
firstCol = start.column
lastRow = iMax
lastCol = jMax

'Set column width to 4
Sheets("Tree").Columns(Cells(firstRow, firstCol).EntireColumn, Cells(firstRow, lastCol - 1).EntireColumn).ColumnWidth = 4
```

Where jMax and iMax are 2 integers. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: What is `start`?

Comment: @BigBen A range. But I already made sure that all 6 values initialized above are integers and they have the expected values, so that should not be the problem!! Something is wrong with the syntax of the last row setting the column width

Comment: `Columns` takes a column letter or index as its argument, not a `Range`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Worksheet.Columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Columns) takes column letter(s) or index as its argument.

So `Sheets("Tree").Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 4`, or `Sheets("Tree").Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 4` are examples of the correct syntax. But you have `Range` arguments here.

If you change `Columns` to `Range`, and all of your variables have the expected values, the last line should work.

A couple recommendations:

- Change the `Integer`s to `Long` - Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle, and there's no real benefit to using `Integer`.
- With variable declaration, you need to explicitly state the type for each variable and not just at the end - `Dim firstRow as Long, firstCol as Long`. With `Dim firstRow, firstCol as Long`, `firstRow` is actually a `Variant`
- Since a `Range` already has `Row` and `Column` properties, it's preferable to avoid using those terms as variables.